# Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager'

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, transactionmanager

I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in file [C:\Users\Tecnico1\Documents\workspace-sts-3.2.0.RELEASE\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\marshall\WEB-INF\classes\META-INF\spring\applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting bean property 'entityManagerFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in file [C:\Users\Tecnico1\Documents\workspace-sts-3.2.0.RELEASE\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\marshall\WEB-INF\classes\META-INF\spring\applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on 
………
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in file [C:\Users\Tecnico1\Documents\workspace-sts-3.2.0.RELEASE\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\marshall\WEB-INF\classes\META-INF\spring\applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on
….….
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on com.springsource.marshall.domain.DocumentoReservaHabitacion.reservaHabitacionId references an unknown entity: com.springsource.marshall.domain.ReservaHabitacion
…………
```

I'm a begginer and I don't find the mistake... Maybe I have duplicate jars... In that case... what jar I have to remove??

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Your entity `com.springsource.marshall.domain.ReservaHabitacion` is not mapped in `hibernate.cfg.xml` file or you are missing `@Entity` annotation on that class.